# Moving React app to Server side rendering with babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I am trying to make a React app created with `react create app` to do server side rendering.

The project uses es6 and imports, which node doesn't seem to support yet.

What would be an easy way to have the server side rendering "work"?

I've tried:

- compiling the js using babel and running it with express JS

  - works, but I don't get the correct backtrace pointing to the source files, it points to the compiled file (maybe a sourcemap would help?)
- running the server with express JS and changing imports to requires and removing class constants inside the class body to make it compatible with what node.js can run
- running it with babel-node - sounds good, but I haven't been able to make this 
  work at all

Since there are multiple ways to go about it, I am wondering what is the best practice so I don't paint myself into a corner.

Comment: `"running it with babel-node - sounds good, but I haven't been able to make this work at all"` That's the way to do it, show what you have tried and what error messages you got.

Answer (score 0):

> The project uses es6 and imports, which node doesn't seem to support
>   yet.

Can be solved with babel.

```
// index.js
require("babel-register");
require("./server");

// server.js
import express from 'express'
// ^^^ new-style import works :)
```

I don't remember having any problems with incorrect backtraces using babel this way.